# Replacing an sink cabinet (48") with a double sink (36")

Tags: flooring, sink, cabinets

This is a very old kitchen. The cabinet I removed was there for most like ~30 years (minimum 20). I removed it but not sure of the next steps. The walls from what I can tell are plasterboard.
The floor had 4 layers of linoleum that I removed. The bottom is wood. That black stuff looks like residue from the bottom of the linoleum layer.
**Question 1:** Do I need to remove that black residue or can I put stuff on top of it?

**Question 2**: My basic plan is to put tiles. But not sure how to do that over the hardwood floor. Can I just put a layer of cement / let it harden and then do thinset+tiles?

**Question 3**: Lower right corner it looks like the plasterboard piece came off, and there is that crack going across. Are there any risks concerning it? I was thinking to just leave it be and put the next cabinet in.

**Question 4**: The new cabinet is 36". Which leaves me with 12". The only good 12" space is between the sink and the oven (on the other side even though it looks like more the 12" length is right over the water pipe handle - not sure if it will fit. Are there safety considerations about having a 12inch cabinet in this space?

**Question 5:** as far as the plumbing I am not planning to do any of that myself, but I am worried because the new sink is double sink (ikea) and I am not sure if it will work well if the pipe is in that location with both sink drains located to the right of it.

(poor representation of the sink with relative drain pipe if I put it all the way to the right)

```
||
  |\       /\       /|
  | \--_--/  \--_--/ |
  |   | |      | |   |
  |                  |  
   ||
```

Would the above be a potential problem for connecting the 2 drains to the wall drain pipe?

This is what the space looks like right now(that range is getting replace later too):
[image: space for cabinet sink]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If height is an issue, use 1/4" concrete backer board, screwed and glued down on your floor. Be sure to use backer board screws and alternate seams so tiles won't crack or shift. If height is not an issue, use 1/2". Then, thinset your tiles on the backer board.

There shouldn't be any issue with the 12" cabinet. You could use a taller cabinet to create a division of workstations (stove/sink). You could have an open spice storage on the raised area on the stove side. The front could have a fake draw front on it.

Seems like no problem piping the double sink drains.